# How do I call Ant Builts using Maven

Tags: php, maven, ant

I have many sub modules of php projects which are run using ANT [It just copies files and runs SQL].

Now I need to Implement Maven for handling future Unit Testing + [Maven is the Best tool which we anyway need to use in the future.]

I have installed Maven for php in Eclipse. I have made a new project using Maven in the IDE itself. I can run the Project also.
[I am a noob to Maven but good with `ANTs`]

Now I want to call those submodular ANT's xml using the Maven project. 
There is [ANT RUN](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) which does the trick for maven, but I am not able to:

- figure out how to reference modules' `ANT xml` outside the Maven Project.
- Ant just merely linking the XML would do the job? Or do I need more dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Maven [ant runner plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to invoke the ANT logic, using ANT's [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task

## Example

```
$ tree
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- ant
            |-- module1
            |   `-- build.xml
            `-- module2
                `-- build.xml

5 directories, 3 files
```

### pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <property name="src.dir" location="${project.build.directory}/../src"/>
                                <subant>
                                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/build.xml"/>
                                </subant>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

ANT is configured to run during the "compile" phase of the Maven build. The ANT logic uses the [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task to run external ANT logic.

### Run example

```
$ mvn compile
..    
..
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ demo ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:

main:
     [echo] module1: hello world

main:
     [echo] module2: hello world
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.394s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 27 20:25:35 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ok It works with utmost charm.. Thanks. Can you help me understand the meaning of `**` in `includes="**/build.xml"`. I made a mistake and was using `*` only.. It didn't work.

Comment: **/build.xml will recurse down thru the subdirectories. For more information I recommend the ANT doco: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task inside [target](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html#target) configuration element of Maven's Ant Run plugin.

Comment: Thanks, But I was looking for External modular target.

Comment: What's "external modular target"?