# Calling Ant targets via Maven

Tags: ant, maven-2

### I can do this

run ANT `build.xml` from Maven using `ant run plugin`.

My `pom.xml`

```
<target>
  <property name="src.dir" location="my_project_folder_location"/>
  <subant>
     <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/build.xml"/>
  </subant>
</target>
```

This runs ANT with `build.xml`

```
 <project name="*ant_test" basedir=".">
    <copy overwrite="true" force="true" verbose="true" todir="to_folder">
        <fileset dir="from_folder" />
    </copy>
 </project>
```

It does the task of copying from 1 folder to another.

### What I need to do is:

Run this new `build.xml` with `<target>`.

```
 <project name="*ant_test" basedir=".">
   <target name="onlyCopy">
    <copy overwrite="true" force="true" verbose="true" todir="to_folder">
        <fileset dir="from_folder" />
    </copy>
  </target>
 </project>
```

What changes should I make in the `pom.xml`

### EDIT

The difference between [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10339712/1354000) and  is:

In the ANT `build.xml` I have mentioned `<targer>`. Target allows independent tasks to be run by selecting the target name from ANT builtfire.

Comment: You've only provided extracts from the ant build.xml, rather than the maven-ant-tasks plugin configuration in the pom.

Comment: @amaidment the ANT file is only that. As i Mentioned before, the Maven runs it and copies files as mentioned in the ANT xml when i dont have <target> set in ANT xml.

Comment: You're not being terribly clear what you want. It sounds like you want an example of how in invoke ANT from Maven......

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call Ant Builts using Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339712/how-do-i-call-ant-builts-using-maven)

Comment: that question was asked by me.. And this question is a bit different..

Comment: @Suhani It's not just me who can't see the difference... Sorry, you need to rephrase the question or run the risk of others voting to close this question.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks for pointing it out, I have edited the question. Also I would mention again, its a very small difference of `<target>` in the build.xml

Comment: @MarkO'Connor its indeed a small difference. I missed it too while reading the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is to Run ANT with all the targets without individually running each target.

You can simply add a target in subant of your `pom.xml`

`<subant target="onlyCopy">` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of invoking ANT from Maven see the following answer:

[How do I call Ant Builts using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339712/how-do-i-call-ant-builts-using-maven/10356762#10356762)